# Is this a legit question?

Tags: storage, memory-usage

I see an interview question thats goes like this:

```
Assuming you have an array with numbers 1 to N. Where N is at most 32,000. 
This array may have duplicates and you do not know what N is. With, 4KB of 
memory available, how would best print all duplicate elements in this array?
```

If i'm not wrong, printing elements does not cost memory. Unless stored into a buffer and print from it. Otherwise, i think this question is flawed. The question should be asking how best can you store the duplicates with a 4KB memory limit.

[Edit]
I'm trying to ask if this is a valid interview question. And if it is, what is the question trying to achieve?

My thoughts about this interview question would be to find a way to store duplicates efficiently using limited memory storage.

I'm not sure which stack community, this question belongs to. So some moderator please help me.

Comment: Won't you need to store some of the duplicates in order to print them all? E.g. Store a number, scan the rest, and repeat?

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, before print the duplicate elements it needs to be stored into a proper container that reduce memory footprint for duplicate numbers. 
What i'm asking is, is that last line of the question correct?
My interpret the last sentence to find a solution to best print duplicates using 4KB memory? 
Does that question also asked about storing it as well? or just printing the variables.

Comment: It's a perfectly legitimate interview question. I'm not going to answer it for you. I'm not sure it's on topic here.

Comment: It is an odd question. Like you say you do not need any additional (data) memory, just a couple of local variables. It is unclear what they mean by "best". Quickly? Using less memory? Little code? This would just annoy me. I guess one should kindly explain the question cannot be answered and why. Perhaps this is the idea.

Comment: see [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Comment: You obviously did not understand the gist of question, so yes, it is great for an interview, since you need to ask further questions to the interviewer to understand it - and from the kind of questions you ask them, they can check your communication any analysing skills. (Hint: the expected solution has something to do with 4000 bytes containing 32000 bits).

Comment: @gnat, yeah i knw it is kinda wrong to put here, but i'm not sure which SO community it belongs to for this question.

Comment: @kevincline, i'm trying to understand how is it a legitimate question? I already answered this question to the interview. Now i'm trying to understand and learn from this. My answer is to loop through the array and store the distinct values as keys and occurrences as value into a KV map to minimus the memory footprint.

Comment: its a standard question. you got it wrong : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605766/how-to-find-a-duplicate-element-in-an-array-of-shuffled-consecutive-integers

Comment: "Assuming you have an array with numbers 1 to N" - does that mean an array with N elements, or are the elements themselves in this range? Are you sure that your KV map can fit into the 4KB memory? The question, I think, has less to do with printing, than it has to do with how to go about finding the duplicates given the constraints.

Comment: @Ewan: not the same question

Comment: @kevincline yes, but could you read the answers to that one and still think a KV map is the right answer to this one?

Comment: @Ewan: you are right, it is a standard question, but honestly, your comment gives me the impression you got it wrong, too. The problem is a variation of the one presented in chapter 1, column 1 or [Programming Pearls 2nd edition](https://tfetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ProgrammingPearls2nd.pdf) by Jon Bentley. The idea is to utilize a bit vector with 32000 bits.

Comment: @DocBrown impressions make an imp out of press and ions, clearly my link works on a higher level of thought

Comment: @DocBrown your link is an interesting solution, i would have gone for a bubble sort and final run through, assuming that the input is part of the memory use and you have one int free for a loop variable or something. Obviously like in my link the key is the hard memory limit

Comment: @Ewan: the problem you linked is different and has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how you *find* the duplicates. Are you just walking along the list, and the duplicates wave at you?
You might need to *remember somehow* all the numbers you already passed, and that takes memory.

Comment: No it doesn't, you can address them one by one, iterating over the entire array each time looking for the first duplicate. Which will be "best" regarding memory use.

Comment: You might need to remember them if you want to avoid printing duplicates twice. But the question doesn't state that. It only says to print them all, which only requires you to print them *at least once*. Unless, again, you are allowed to mutate the array, then you could delete duplicates as you find them.